# Solving the Price of Widgits

Tags: linear-algebra

So I've got a word problem.

A man is selling widgits on the street corner. The price for one widgit is $50. However, for every widgit he sells, he increases the price by 5%. What is the total amount of money it would take to purchase 50 widgits?

What is the fastest way to solve this problem? I can figure the value for each widgit after each is sold and then add them all up but I'm certain there is a faster way. Please help? This has really been bugging me.

Comment: Do you know how to sum geometric progressions?

Answer (score 0):

Let the price of the $n^{th}$ widget sold be $a_n$, then we have:
$a_1 = 50, a_2 = 50(1+0.05) = 52.5,..., a_n = 50(1+0.05)^{n-1} \implies S_{50} = a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_{50} = 50(1+ 1.05 + 1.05^2 +\cdots + 1.05^{49})= ...$